# Cannot enable WSL service on windows 10, error code 0x8007010B The directory name is invalid

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to enable the Windows subsystem service for Linux (WSL) service on my Windows 10, I first tried to start it from GUI but got this error when it appears to be downloading something from the internet.

[image]

I then tried to start the service from the command line but got similar error message like this, though probably with more information to debug

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The directory name is invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Any ideas on what the directory means here? My guess is that there might be some special characters in the path name which blocks the software to be downloaded, but have no clue where to start to investigate.